# Uses of 'was' and 'had' in sentences

Tags: sentence-meaning

This is a extract from a newspaper.

> In the 1960s and 70s, before the men in blue and IPL, when cricketers could still walk around in the street unhindered, Durani was the closest Indian cricket had to a superstar. Decades before Indian cricketers were treated on par with Bollywood superstars, Durani starred in one, alongside Parveen Babi

In this paragraph the sentence:-

"Durani was the closet Indian cricket had to superstar "

I didn't understand the meaning of this sentence and I doubted the sentence may be grammatically wrong.

Please someone help me out regarding the meaning of this sentence and whether the sentence is grammatically correct or not?

Comment: to **a** superstar. That's editing, and not really allowed. :)

Answer (score 1):

It works like this:

> Did Indian cricket have a superstar?

No, not quite:

> Durani was the closest thing to a superstar that Indian cricket had.

Rearrange to move the relative clause before the complement of "closest":

> Durani was the closest thing that Indian cricket had to a superstar.

Delete unnecessary words:

> Durani was the closest Indian cricket had to a superstar.